# Actual filesystem path to sources is visible on browser in deployed app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nginx, webpack

I have a deployed Express app running on a nginx reverse proxy.
I'm using the MERN stack, and while the app runs without problem, I was checking the sources tab while inspecting in Chrome and found out that my actual filesystem path to the sourcecode is visible there.

I see something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/INN4F.jpg

**my actual folders and username are shown**

I expected that the build directory would be the only thing shown and I think this is a serious security breach and I would like to fix it.

I'm using Node.js, Express, nginx as a reverse proxy, webpack and ReactJS if it helps.

Ive already looked through my package.json scripts and everything points to the actual build/ directory.

**Edit**: This is only visible on Chrome, not on Firefox. I dont have access to IE or Safari at the moment.

Comment: Have you set up a workspace in Google Chrome? If you have - then this is why you'd be able to see the folders - google chrome is actually reading from the file system and displaying the contents. The files would not be actually visible for browsers.

Comment: As far as I know, I have not. I do have the React Dev extension though, although I would only expect it to show the folders while in 'development' mode, not production.

Comment: This should not be shown, unless you've allowed access to chrome to the filesystem. Not 100% sure it would work, but you could try opening an incognito window to see if the files are still showing in the developer tools.

Comment: It is still there, even on a test user account. Tomorrow I'll try on a different computer.

Comment: @VasilDininski I found the solution to this. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing this behaviour:

`create-react-app` points  `webpack` to make source maps (files that map the minified and compiled versions of the source code to the absolute path of the original files) and bundles them in the production build.

To avoid this, I just deleted the *.map files by modifying the build script in `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "export GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false && react-scripts build",
    ...
},
```

This however makes it more difficult to debug production code. See [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/2742#issuecomment-313658034).